# small quantity of sugar

Tags: meaning, quantificational-nouns

a. We repaired the heater with some little difficulty.

b. We repaired the heater with no little difficulty.

How much difficulty did we encounter? A lot, a little, a certain amount...?

---

c. He added some small quantity of sugar to the coffee.

Did he add a lot of sugar, a little sugar or...

Many thanks

Comment: "some little" and "no little" aren't very common; the former in particular is rare. If you're talking about sizes, especially in casual contexts, you should normally use something else, e.g. "a lot of", "some", "a little". It's not clear if you're asking specifically about "some little" and "no little", or just want phrases for a lot and a little.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I was looking for the meanings of the expressions. I don't use them. 'Some little difficulty' might be common in the US, or might have been common there. I saw it in the novel "Frannie and Zooey" by Salinger. I couldn't find the sentence in google books so I didn't put in a link. I had never heard that expression and found it odd.

Comment: Salinger is a writer and I would expect it there, if at all, to see that kind of thing in a novel. But it is not especially AmE. Probably just the schoolboys in the book...That said, We repaired the heater with some small difficulty. is more usual.

Answer (score 1):

Your two examples of 'sugar' and 'difficulty' are not really comparable. One is physical, the other is not. The adjective 'little' is both subjective and very flexible. What one person may consider "a little trouble" may be a lot more to another person.

In both your examples, the writer or speaker is conveying that, in their opinion, or from their perspective, it was a little amount.

Answer (score 1):

(a) I find *some little difficulty* a strange expression, but according to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=some+little+difficulty&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) it was especially common in the 19th century.

(b) *No little difficulty* definitely means *a lot of difficulty.*

(c) It would be much more usual to say *a small quantity of sugar* (or, as Astralbee suggests, *a spoonful.*) In other contexts, *some small quantity* would mean 'a small amount, but I don't know exactly how much'.

Comment: We ran into some little [minor] difficulty [or other] during the conference.